# AngularJS and C# app: How to iterate through and select elements from app.data folder for use in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, local-files

How can I navigate through this folder to select elements without hard coding a file path? For example, if app.data has a folder titled img and I want to display all of the images in that folder on my page, my thought was to add these elements to a javascript array and use ng-repeat to display these. In order to do this, I attempted some simple javascript:

```
 var imageCount = 4;
    for (var i = 1; i <= imageCount; i++) {
        var imagePath = "data/Contents/Splash/img0" + i + ".png";
        var image = { image: imagePath };
        };

        $scope.images.push(image)
    }
```

But this is still dependent on me providing an imageCount. Could I loop through this folder in some way and count the elements and store that in imageCount? Based on googling, it looks like I may not be able to do this all in javascript (accessing local folders that is) because it would be a massive security threat.

The c# backend of this app gets all the content needed into the app.data folder. For example the homepage folder has 3 files in it:

```
      01_TabSection1 (a folder)

      02_TabSection2 (a folder)

      03_Splash (image)
```

Is there a way I can iterate through a folder, looking for a specific prefix or filetype, or foldername if it exists, so I can build a url reference to use the elements in these folders in my HTML view?

Am I looking at this all wrong? Is this work that should be done with more c#, or using http get requests, ajax, json? I just came across some php examples of iterating through folders. For some reason I thought I could navigate through local folders with javascript when I initially started.

Thank you for your time, sorry if there are some glaring holes in my knowledge.

Comment: build up the list and structure you want on the server side, and pass it back as a JSON object to the Angular ajax caller.. Angular is client side so its going to rely on your c# server side for info.

Comment: @Pogrindis if I have a local json folder in my data folder can I read that with  jQuery/javascript? Can I use a GET request on a local file?

Comment: Cannner yes you can parse a direct file once its accessible over a http get request.. GET requests are default on http so once its in your web directory you can parse the `.json` just make the call to `GET` it via the angular controller.. For debugging or stepping through use developer tools in chrome or firefox (f12)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can not access content of any ASP.Net folder by just using it's name and file name. But if your folder is not an ASP.Net folder then you can access it as i suggest below.

1. Create an array in controller eg `$scope.ImageList=[]`
2. Create a web api or any action that will return a list of images and assign it to that array.
   ( If you have all images at client side then you can push image's path in that array)

and to render images in view use `ng-repeat` directive

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in ImageList">
     <img ng-src="item" />
  </li>
</ul>
```